Pinching in my model
I'm making a hard surface model of a gameboy advance sp. I auto shade smooth my model and noticed all this pinching on my model and no matter what changes I make from adding new edges to merging vertices, theyre not going away. Does anyone have an answer to this?



Are you talking about the bad shading? Try one of these 2 solutions: Do an inset on these surfaces, or give your object a WeightedNormal modifier, which will prevent the shading on these surfaces

Or manually set the coplanar and flat faces to flat shading. But that's very old school box modeling shenanigans.

please share your file so that we can give a try (only the object with the problem): https://blend-exchange.com/
